# Most optimal way to load/browse wordpress articles

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for a way to browse/load/search articles on Wordpresss blog on external website/application. Originally I thought Wordpress has some basic API which I can use to connect with wordpress and use it for accessing data, but this is not possible. RSS is no flexible enough - It offers only latest articles and does not enable to search or access older articles. That leaves me with a question - is there any other way than writing a plugin and having my potential customers to always go with a struggle to install plugin?

Comment: Do you have permission from the owner of the other site to display that content on other websites?

Comment: Yes, I will. I thought Wordpress has traditional API where I can just authorize access and then just load articles, but... appearently not!

Answer (score 1):

An 'optimal' way would perhaps, be to just provide a hyperlink to the article.

You could have an abstract/ extract if you like, but not the entire article. If the article is your own, you would still follow the same, I suppose.

Comment: Hyperlink won't do. for the sake of simplicity, I want to create some sort of news aggregator - which allows bloggers to opt in and then we get access to their articles. But we need a clear way to do that! and plugin is an uncomfortable way to do so!